# How can I remind a firm to schedule the next interview?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

I attended an interview on 21 December 2019. I successfully cleared the first round. Due to some time restrictions and unavailability of a panel, HR told me she will schedule a telephonic round but she didn't yet. I want to write a reminder letter to her.

Comment: Patience is a virtue... Give them time to contact people.

Comment: Lets be clear here... you had an interview **on a Saturday** and you want to remind them because they did not schedule the call **during all of Sunday**? I don't know what company that is, but do you think they might have something like office hours?

Comment: How urgent is it that you need a job? You _just_ had your first interview yesterday (strangely on a weekend). I'd wait until after the New Year to follow up. I highly doubt many will be in the office during Christmas holidays or even before the New Year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 8):

One day is too soon to be sending a formal reminder; at any time of year you should allow at least 48 hours (not including weekends) to give HR and interviewers time to consult diaries, and in late December in UK/US/Europe it is likely staff are winding down for Christmas already.

Comment: She told me to send reminder letter to her because she was middle of so many activities.

Comment: That’s information to add into your question.

Comment: And the post is winding down too, at least in the UK. If you post a letter tonight, it is unlikely to be received until the 30th.

Answer (score 2):

If the HR person instructed you to send them a reminder then send it the next business day.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment on another answer:

> She told me to send reminder letter to her because she was middle of so many activities.

It sounds like you are simply asking how to phrase such a request?

I would go with something like:

> Hi HR person,
>
> Thank you for giving me the opportunity to interview with your company.
>
> Per our previous communication, you requested that I remind you to schedule a phone interview with me.
>
> The only day which could be problematic for me is Thursday from 9am-1pm so please feel free to suggest any other time.
>
> I hope all is well during this busy holiday season and look forward to the next phase!
>
> Sincerely, Riya sen

If your interview was Saturday then I would wait until Tuesday morning at the earliest to send the reminder.